# Скопировать таблицу скриптом

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Добрый день. Задался таким вопросом. Есть две таблицы они индетичны, но только названия разные, назовем их New и Old. Не могу придумать как сделать так чтобы при условии if содержимое Old копировалось и вставлялось в New.

Comment: inner join и если null в части new брать из old

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Желательно с примером в коде

Comment: [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Хм, это оказалось легче чем я думал.

```
'INSERT INTO New SELECT * FROM Old'
```

Comment: 'INSERT `INTO` New SELECT * FROM Old'

Comment: хм оригинально.

Comment: в других диалектах (например `t-sql`) еще возможен вариант запроса `select  * into new from old` который вдобавок создает таблицу `new`, аналогичную по структуре `old` и заполняет значениями из `old`.

Comment: Опасненько... не надо полагаться на то, что структуры абы идентичны - а ну как в результате ALTER TABLE явно или как побочный эффект сползёт порядок полей?. Лучше в обеих секциях явно указать список полей.